# In Step Functions how to use apigateway invoke with a vpce api endpoint?

Tags: rest, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, vpc-endpoint

I just got the following error:

> Parameters.ApiEndpoint: Invalid format.

The format is `<API_ID>.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com`

My vpce API is something like this: `https://xxxxxxxx-vpce-000000000.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

So I would like to know how to put the vpce endpoint in the ApiEndpoint param from my `apigateway:invoke` without triggering this error.

[Error step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BQqY.png)